# How add PHP in sidebar when using widget?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, sidebar

I have installed sidebar widget, and I have read some article about using php code in WordPress, but I'm trying to insert php code into content in my sidebar.I have added some HTML code, and it works fine, but php code dose not work.

[image]

Is there any solution?

Comment: It's not a good pratice to insert php in widget. Can you edit your theme file and add your php directly in the sidebar.php file ?

Comment: I don't have access to FTP to edit sidebar.php directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with the standard Text Widget.

Have a look at this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/

It adds a widget that you can use for what you want. You still need to use the opening and closing brackets of php:

```
<?php
  // Your code here
?>
```